# How to get image path with koa-multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, koa

I'm creating a image upload RestAPI with Koa multer. I'm saving image with url in database but i'm not able to access this created url. When i open this url it says not found. I have project in E drive. When i create full path from E drive to image then url works and then i can see image with created url. But it's not a correct way i want to get image from project url.

It's creating url like `http://localhost:8000\\src\\images\\image.png`

Project Directory

```
project
│   node_modules
│   package.json   
│
└───src
│   │   views
│   │   migrations
│   │
│   └───images
│       │   image.png
```

API

```
const multer = require('@koa/multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'src\\images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
});

  router.post('/api/image_upload', upload.fields([
        {
            name: 'avatar',
            maxCount: 1
        }
    ]), async (ctx: Koa.Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {

        var user_id = ctx.request.body.user_id;
        if (!user_id) {
            ctx.body = {
                status: 422,
                message: "Please enter user id",
            };
        } else {
            const userCheck = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE id=$1',
                [`${user_id}`]);

                if (ctx.files['avatar']) {
                    var imageName = ctx.files['avatar'][0]['originalname'];
                    var path = ctx.files['avatar'][0]['path'];

                    var host = ctx.host;
                    var avatar = ctx.protocol + "://" + host + "\\" + path;
                } else {
                    avatar = userCheck[0].avatar;
                }
           }
    });
```

Comment: Aren't you specifically creating that path? Appending ctx.protocol and host? Perhaps you're looking for [`require('path').resolve(path)`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Comment: @cubrr I didn't understand. I'm creating localhost path. Isn't it correct? What should i do for creating a path?

Comment: Ah, so do you want an url that you can use on the frontend in an img? You either need to serve the images from a directory with something like `express.static`, or create a route that finds the correct file and passes it to the response (e.g. with fs.createReadStream(...).pipe(res)ö

Comment: @cubrr Yes i need a url but i can't use ``express.static`` because i'm using koa. Can you edit my question so that i can understand it easily. I tried some solutions but didn't work.

Comment: Oh, you're right, my mistake. Koa-static then. The point is that once the user has uploaded the image, you need to serve the image just as you would do with any other image that you have.

Comment: Please share any example or edit this question. It will be very helpful and can save my day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207047/discussion-between-daniyal-mughees-and-cubrr).